# Unpausing and Pausing a dag in python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

Scenario:

I make a POST call that triggers a process to export a file, this call returns an Export-ID. This process can take an unknown amount of time to complete, so I have to make a GET call using the Export-ID periodically to see if the process is completed, this GET call returns a STATUS every time and a URL to the download location once the export has been completed.

Goal:

I want to create a Dag that kicks off this export, and then waits 20 minutes and sends the GET request to see if the URL is present, meaning the export has completed.

Issue:

Since we don't know how long it will take for the export to complete we don't want this Dag to be stuck in an idle state waiting 20 minutes to check if the export is complete, holding up resources. Is there a way to pause/stop this dag, releasing resources for this period.

What I thought of doing:
Create Dag that has 2 tasks:
    Task 1: Kick off Export
    Task 2: unpause a second dag that checks and is schedule to run in the interval we want to check at
    Dag completed

Subdag 1 task:
    Task 1: get export-ID, check if url is available if so kick-off download then pause the dag once downloaded. If the url is not available, complete the dag and re-run again in the interval set.

Is this a good route to take? If so why not and what is better. I have not found anything API wise that lets me pause and unpause a dag using python, is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried any thing ? Post your code so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup your process such that `submit_export >> consume_export` and if the export isn't yet ready have `consume_export` fail -- then put a `retries` and suitable retry interval for however long you want to keep trying.

Alternatively, if you want to know that the export was completed but the consumer step failed you could do `submit_export >> wait_export >> consume_export`, then if you see `wait_export` failed you'll know the export didn't appear in a timely manner.